# Is it possible to change the text color in a string to multiple colors in Java?

Tags: java, android, string, textcolor

What I mean is, is it possible to change the text "This text is blue" to the color blue in a single string? There must be a way...

```
<TextView
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:text="This text is white. This text is blue."
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="22dp"/>
```

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Yes, its possible. For this you need to use [`SpannableString`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) and [`ForegroundColorSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html).

This should look something like this:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

String red = "this is red";
SpannableString redSpannable= new SpannableString(red);
redSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, red.length(), 0);
builder.append(redSpannable);

String white = "this is white";
SpannableString whiteSpannable= new SpannableString(white);
whiteSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, white.length(), 0);
builder.append(whiteSpannable);

String blue = "this is blue";
SpannableString blueSpannable = new SpannableString(blue);
blueSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, blue.length(), 0);
builder.append(blueSpannable);

mTextView.setText(builder, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

[image]

Comment: You forgot to set the buffer type in your last line

Comment: Just curious... Would this need to go in a separate class? I'm working with android, so would it need to be in the MainActivity class?

Comment: It may go in separate class if you want to. But it can be in `MainActivity` as well. There is no restriction on this, but you need to have access to `TextView` you want to set `SpannableString` to.

Comment: @ jrobinson3k1, its working without buffer type in my case. But I still think its better to specify `BufferType`. Thanks for correction.

Comment: @inazaruk Good to know that `TextView` will automatically determine the type passed in if you don't specify. I've always just specified so I never knew. Thanks.

Comment: How would you do this for a color AND a style (italics or bold) at the same time?

Comment: Not working for me on `android 7.0` in `AlertDialog`'s `setMessage()`

Answer (score 12):

A simple way to do it is to use HTML and set the text to the `TextView` programmatically.

```
String text = "This text is white. <font color=\"blue\">This text is blue.</font>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text), BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: What if you are referencing a string in string.xml?

Comment: how to pass a string inside `<font color=\"blue\">This text is blue.</font>";`

Answer (score 8):

Try this..

```
TextView update= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.address);
String colorText= "Driver is nearby "
                + "<font color=\"#E72A02\"><bold>"
                + "43, KR Rd, Tata Silk Farm, Jayanagar"
                + "</bold></font>"
                + " and he is "
                + "<font color=\"#B92000\"><bold>"
                + "11 km"
                + "</bold></font>"
                + " & "
                + "<font color=\"#B92000\"><bold>"
                + "20 mins"
                + "</bold></font>"
                + " away from your current location.";

        update.setText(Html.fromHtml(colorText));
```

and the **result** will be like this..

[image: result]

Answer (score 4):

### `Html.fromHtml(String)` is deprecated in Android N

To support latest version of Android so something like this

```
 val colorText = ("Some Normal Text\n" 
                    + "<font color=\"#FFA500\"><bold> Orange Text </bold></font>"
                    + "More Normal text")

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            venueAddressValue.setText(Html.fromHtml(colorText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        } else {
            venueAddressValue.setText(Html.fromHtml(colorText));
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:
In a fragment :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.shipment_accepted_fragment,
                container, false);

        String email = "(abc@gmail.com)";

        TextView shipment_email = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.textview);
        String text_shipment_email = "Hello"
                + " <font color='"
                + getResources().getColor(R.color.green_color) + "'>" + email
                + "</font>"
                + "Bye";
        shipment_email.setText(Html.fromHtml(text_shipment_email),
                TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a class like this:

```
import android.text.SpannableStringBuilder;
import android.text.style.CharacterStyle;

public class StyleableSpannableStringBuilder extends SpannableStringBuilder {
    public StyleableSpannableStringBuilder appendWithStyle(CharacterStyle c, CharSequence text) {
        super.append(text);
        int startPos = length() - text.length();
        setSpan(c, startPos, length(), 0);
        return this;
    }

    public StyleableSpannableStringBuilder appendWithStyle(CharacterStyle [] c, CharSequence text) {
        super.append(text);
        int startPos = length() - text.length();
        for (CharacterStyle c1 : c)
            setSpan(c1, startPos, length(), 0);         
        return this;
    }       
}
```

This allows me to do things like this:

```
private void buildTickerItem(DelayedQuoteServiceObject o)
{   
    Double lastPrice = Double.parseDouble(o.getValue("LastPrice"));
    Double dayChange = Double.parseDouble(o.getValue("DayChange"));
    Double percentChange = Double.parseDouble(o.getValue("PercentDayChange")) / 100;

    if (o.isIndex() == true)
    {

        tickerTapeData.appendWithStyle(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),o.getDisplayName());            
        tickerTapeData.append(" "+ indexFormat.format(lastPrice) + " (");

        if (dayChange >= 0)
            tickerTapeData.appendWithStyle(new ForegroundColorSpan(Colours.getTickerPositive()), indexFormat.format(dayChange));        
        else
            tickerTapeData.appendWithStyle(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), indexFormat.format(dayChange));
    }
    else
    {
        tickerTapeData.appendWithStyle(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), o.ticker);

        tickerTapeData.append("@"+ dollarFormat.format(lastPrice) + " (");              

        if (dayChange >= 0)
            tickerTapeData.appendWithStyle(new ForegroundColorSpan(Colours.getTickerPositive()), dollarFormat.format(dayChange));       
        else
            tickerTapeData.appendWithStyle(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), dollarFormat.format(dayChange));


    }

    tickerTapeData.append("/");


    if (dayChange >= 0)
        tickerTapeData.appendWithStyle(new ForegroundColorSpan(Colours.getTickerPositive()), percentFormat.format(percentChange));      
    else
        tickerTapeData.appendWithStyle(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), percentFormat.format(percentChange));

    tickerTapeData.append(")  ");       
}
```

To create a ticker tape.  Works pretty nicely and keeps the code clean.

Comment: Again I must ask, how do you append multiple styles at the same time? For example, say you want to display some words blue, some italics, and some both?

Comment: Scott, it accepts an array of CharacterStyles so you could call the appendWithStyle(new CharacterStyle[] { new ForegroundColorSpan(BLUE), new StyleSpan(ITALICS)}, "Blue italicized text");

Answer (score 1):

It's simple really. Just add these in your value/string.xml

```
<string name = 'string_name'><font color='#000000'>This is black</font><font color='#ffffff'>This is white</font></string>
```

Then add the name of that string to your XML resource file

Answer (score 0):

I am use for a change star if service **"Onward"**

```
String c = "*" + getResources().getString(R.string.rupee) + str_pay_at_store;
SpannableString spannable2 = new SpannableString(c);
spannable2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 1, 
Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv_payatstore.setText(spannable2);
```

You can see like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "<font color=#000>this color is black </font><font color=#6ab04c>this color is green</font>";

textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```