# How can I make the text in TextView be two different sizes?

Tags: android, xml, textedit

I want to  write a line in a TextView where the second word is a quarter of the size of the first word.  In my string.xml file I used large and small and it did not work to the extent I want it to.  I also tried changing the text size in the main.xml, but it only lets you do that once in a TextEdit.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

If what you need is to specify different font sizes for the text in a TextView from XML you can assign a string like this:

```
<string name="hello"><big><big>Hello Big Text!</big></big>\n<small>Hello small text</small></string>
```

and use this string in the TextView. Note that the newline is '`\n`' instead of `<br/>`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question: [Is it possible to change the text color in a string to multiple colors in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405661/is-it-possible-to-change-the-text-color-in-a-string-to-multiple-colors-in-java/8405694#8405694)

But instead of `ForegroundColorSpan` you should use [`TextAppearanceSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TextAppearanceSpan.html) or [`AbsoluteSizeSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/AbsoluteSizeSpan.html).

Comment: In the java it is possible. I am wondering if I can do it in the xml

Comment: No, you can't. You'll need to use java one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `fromHTML` method of the [HTML](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) class.

This way you can format the string using basic HTML `<font>` tags