# How to align a TextView to the right of another TextView which breaks to the next line?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, textview

The problem I am having is aligning the second `TextView` to the right of the `TextView` which spans to two lines.

I am using a `RelativeLayout`, but when I use `layout_toRightOf` it appears at the top of the screen, and when I add `layout_alignRight` it disappears.

I am very confused how this works. You would assume that it would follow where the first `TextView` ends, but it does not. Oh, and I am using `wrap_content` on width and height incase anyone thinks that's the problem. Thanks in advance.

XML

```
<TextView 
            android:id="@+id/edit_event_name_show"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/show_event_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edit_event_name_show"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/edit_event_name_show" />
```

**EDIT**: To anyone that ever has a similar issue with trying to align things nicely with TextViews, there is not a way by default. But you can use `SpannableString` and build them using `SpannableStringBuilder`.

Comment: Please include the code that you are using and a screenshot if it will help.

Comment: I did, I shouldn't need to include every case I have tried. But if you think its necessary I will post the xml. Also, just a heads up, if I do not include `android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/edit_event_name_show"` it will just appear at the very top of the screen. So thats why I put it there. It worked for my Buttons,

Comment: "I shouldn't need to include every case I have tried." You are correct, I only wanted an idea of what you were doing. Often a code sample expresses an idea better than words. What you included is great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Third Attempt (Successful Attempt)**

I believe this will help you and be much easier than the other stuff.

Try using this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405661/is-it-possible-to-change-the-text-color-in-a-string-to-multiple-colors-in-java/8405694#8405694), but change font size instead of color.

Sam's answer sums up the link. *(in case the link dies at some point.)*

**Second Attempt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edit_event_name_show"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:text=" test 1     jfalksjdflkjasdfj"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/show_event_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/edit_event_name_show"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:text="test2          adjfalsjdfla fa sdfasdf asf a"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Picture:

[image]

---

**First Attempt**

Why not surround your `TextViews` with a `LinearLayout`. It will keep them better organized and a little cleaner.

Try this and let me know how it goes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edit_event_name_show"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:text="test1"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/show_event_type"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:text="test2"
            android:textSize="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Picture:

[image]

---

With long text:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, well I originally had it like that without a RelativeLayout base Layout, but thats an interesting way to go about it. I thought the point of a RelativeLayout was to avoid doing what you just did though. And do me a favor, try it with a longer text. That doesn't really replicate my example.

Comment: Long text added. If this is not what you are looking for, can you clarify a little more in your original post? Thanks

Comment: See my edit at the top. I should have been clear that thats not what I wanted. Sorry!

Comment: That is strange... lol. One second. Let me see if i can figure out what you mean.

Comment: Haha, yea. Sorry about that. Hopefully my explanation makes sense. If not let me know.

Comment: Is that more along the lines of what you are talking about?

Comment: Closer, but not there. Imagine not moving the secondTextViews position but the first one is longer and breaks to the next line. I want the second smaller TextView to be to the right of it in that manner. I'd provide an image if I could find one, but havent been able to. Like in my example image issue above, take that smaller text and stick it on the second line of the first TextView. Reason why I can't concatenate the strings together is because I need the text size difference

Comment: You may need to draw a picture. However, i believe i understand what you are saying. I believe that is not possible. To make it possible you will need to create your own `View` probably. Because the `TextView`, by design (i believe), will take up the entire width of the new line. So, you cant really put a new `View` there. You would have to draw it manually there or something and that sounds extremely painful.

Comment: Damn! No wonder I couldn't find anything on that. Thanks for trying and you basically answered my question, even though its not what I was hoping for lol. Could you just add that at the top for others who have the similar thought.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405661/is-it-possible-to-change-the-text-color-in-a-string-to-multiple-colors-in-java/8405694#8405694 I posted it in my answer too, just do font size instead of color. Hopefully that will help, ill check back a little later.

Answer (score 3):

**Using Spannables**

I had left the conversation to fiddle with Spannables and created this:

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(18);

        String first = "A sentence that contains enough balderdash, blather and babble to wrap at least once.";
        String second = " (Normal)";

        Spannable span = new SpannableString(first + second);
        span.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, first.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        span.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.7f), first.length(), span.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        textView.setText(span);
        setContentView(textView);
    }
}
```

But prolink007 has already given you a generic link... Oh well. I'm posting it anyway.

Comment: Interesting approach. Let me try it.

Comment: If you expect one of these to not wrap around, ie both are one word text, then this will look a little goofy.

Comment: I will post an image of what I get when I do what you said. It doesn't look as expected. But thanks for the time :)

Comment: There are lots of other ways to do this. The trouble is I'm not sure what look you expect...

Comment: For the smaller TextView to be right next to the Bigger TextView, but next to it on the second line.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear on that. I would just make it a single string, except I want the text sizes to be different.

Comment: I decided to use `AbsoluteSizeSpan` since I needed the Text size difference, but this is great! I never knew this class existed. It was great to learn it. Thanks to you and @prolink007.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="hiangdnfaljiadnk" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news_summary"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/news_title"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25sp"             android:text="hiangdnfaljiadnkfjfaingaldnfasidognkahiangdnfaljiadnkfjfaingaldnfasidognkahiangdnfaljiadnkfjfaingaldnfasidognka"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news_from"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/news_summary"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="1111111" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news_comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/news_summary"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="3333333" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: picture]

Comment: you should add some description to your answer for better understanding