# Color Single Letters in JavaFX Buttontexts

Tags: button, javafx-2, letters, text-coloring

the title already describes my problem. I want to color single letters or sequences of letters in a JFX Button but not the whole text. I found a solution for swing components [Is it possible to change the text color in a string to multiple colors in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405661/is-it-possible-to-change-the-text-color-in-a-string-to-multiple-colors-in-java) but not for javafx yet. Can anyone help me plz?

Answer (score 4):

Check this out

```
public class ColoredButtonTextDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

        HBox coloredTextBox = HBoxBuilder.create().spacing(0).children(
                LabelBuilder.create().text("Say ").textFill(Color.YELLOW).build(),
                LabelBuilder.create().text("'").textFill(Color.DARKBLUE).build(),
                LabelBuilder.create().text("Hell").textFill(Color.RED).build(),
                LabelBuilder.create().text("o ").textFill(Color.GREEN).build(),
                LabelBuilder.create().text("W").textFill(Color.BLUE).build(),
                LabelBuilder.create().text("orld!").textFill(Color.DARKMAGENTA).build(),
                LabelBuilder.create().text("'").textFill(Color.DARKBLUE).build()//
                ).build();

        btn.setGraphic(coloredTextBox);
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is just the FXML form of Uluk Biy's answer:

```
<Button>
    <graphic>
        <HBox spacing="0.0">
            <Label text="Colors " style="-fx-text-fill: yellow; -fx-background-color: #1156cf;" />
            <Label text="are " style="-fx-text-fill: red; -fx-background-color: #11cf56;" />
            <Label text="cool!" style="-fx-text-fill: blue; -fx-background-color: #cf1156;" />
        </HBox>
    </graphic>
</Button>
```

...and yes, I love answering 7 years old questions. ;-)