# how to set color for string in EditText

Tags: android

I am appending String to Editbox.
here appendToMessageHistory is method.
I want to set separate separate color for the Both String Username and messge
 please give solution before you vote down and think it is not relevent in android.

```
 public void appendToMessageHistory(String username, String message) {
            if (username != null && message != null) {
                messageHistoryText.append(username + ":");
                messageHistoryText.append(message + "\n" + "\n");
            }
        }
```

any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: you can use Html.fromHtml()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the text color in a string to multiple colors in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405661/is-it-possible-to-change-the-text-color-in-a-string-to-multiple-colors-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String htmlText = "<font color=#cccccc>" + username+"</font> <font color=#ffeecc>"+ message+"</font>";
messageHistoryText.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText));
```

Try this hope it will help.

[public static Spanned fromHtml (String source)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `SpannableString`.

```
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(editText.getText().toString());
int lastIndex = //index to be used
spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),0,lastIndex, 0);
editText.setText(spannableString);
```

Check this nice [Tutorial.](http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2014/03/android-spannablestring-example.html)