# How to change color of text between two different type of braces

Tags: android

I have a string for example: `My (favourite) {website} is (stackoverflow)`

I want to change the color of that between curly brace and rouded brace so what I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set color of TextView span in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282940/set-color-of-textview-span-in-android)

Comment: Use `Spannable` text, if the character starts with any type of brace, check the preceding `char` if it is equal to the end brace of the starting brace. Then apply the color from `n` to `n-1` char.

Comment: Can you please show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

It is done by creating a `SpannableStringBuilder` like shown below:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

String red = "this is red";
SpannableString redSpannable= new SpannableString(red);
redSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, red.length(), 0);
builder.append(redSpannable);

String white = "this is white";
SpannableString whiteSpannable= new SpannableString(white);
whiteSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE), 0, white.length(), 0);
builder.append(whiteSpannable);

textView.setText(builder, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

For more information look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405661/is-it-possible-to-change-the-text-color-in-a-string-to-multiple-colors-in-java)